# How to send data to Google Spread Sheet using POST method on Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am writing cross platform applications on Xamarin Forms. I would like to post data captured by mobile applications to google spreadsheet. How do I start from here?

Answer (score 0):

**https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/**

Google Sheets API
Reads and writes Google Sheets.

Service: sheets.googleapis.com
All URIs below are relative to https://sheets.googleapis.com

This service provides the following discovery document:

https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4

You can see more here!